# Why isn't there a 'nonnil' attribute for clang?

Tags: objective-c, attributes, clang

`nonnull` works for C functions but not obj-c methods. To be clear, I am suggesting this

```
- (void)doSomethingWithRequiredString:(NSString * __attribute((nonnil)))requiredString
                                  bar:(NSString *)optionalString);
```

or (more like nonnull)

```
- (void)doSomethingWithRequiredString:(NSString *)requiredString
                                  bar:(NSString *)optionalString)
__attribute((nonnil(0)));
```

I have puzzled over whether or not there is a good technical reason. I understand that clang could only really use the attribute for a compile time check or static analysis, but that seems orthogonal. Is there some strong reason *not* to have this?

Comment: My suspicion: `clang` is a huge project. Its developers have better things to do.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You totally can.  The only thing you're doing wrong is thinking that method parameters are 0-indexed, when in fact they're 1-indexed (oh, and it's `nonnull`, not `nonnil`):

```
- (void)doSomethingWithRequiredString:(NSString *)requiredString
                                  bar:(NSString *)optionalString
        __attribute((nonnull(1)));
```

Now when you try to use that:

```
id thing = ...;
[thing doSomethingWithRequiredString:nil bar:@"42"];
```

Xcode will warn you with a by saying "Null passed to a callee which requires a non-null argument".

Also, if you leave out the "(1)" portion of the __attribute, it's assumed that the non-nil requirement applies to *all* parameters.

Clang recognizes the GCC attributes, and GCC's definition of the `nonnull` attribute is here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bnonnull_007d-function-attribute-1733

---

Update: As of [Xcode 6.3](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=22) a cleaner syntax is supported.

In properties and methods the keywords are `nullable`, `nonnull` and `null_unspecified`.

So your method signature would become this:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithRequiredString:(nonnull NSString *)requiredString
                                  bar:(nullable NSString *)optionalString;
```

Comment: Many thanks. It was the indexing that got me. That was unexpected.

Comment: @griotspeak yeah, that threw me for a loop too.

Comment: @DaveDeLong is there an easier per–parameter version of this attribute, similar to `__unused`?

Comment: @danyowdee I'm not sure what you mean; I show how to do a "per parameter" attribute above...

Comment: @DaveDeLong let me rephrase that: the `nonnull` attribute is postfix for the function, and has (an optional) argument list, limiting its effect to a subset of that function’s parameters. I was wondering whether there’s also an infix version, that would allow attributing the parameter at the position where it is declared along the lines of `-fooWith:(__nonnull id)cannotBeNil baz:(id)canBeNil andBlafa:(__nonnull id)cannotBeNilEither;` instead of `-fooWith:cannotBeNil baz:canBeNil andBlafa:cannotBeNilEither __attribute__((nonnull(1,3)));`.

Comment: @danyowdee Aha, I see what you mean; thanks for clarifying. Unfortunately, there is no infix syntax for this.

Comment: @danyowdee [You may be interested in this](http://freshbsd.org/commit/llvm/r199467)

Comment: @DaveDeLong \o/ those are great news!

Comment: `#define __nonnull(indices...) __attribute__((nonnull(indices)))`

Answer (score 0):

In the Xcode 6.3 beta new Objective-C features have been added to express (non)nullability in headers: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=22

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

You may code like this:

```
- (nullable AAPLListItem *)itemWithName:(nonnull NSString *)name;
- (NSInteger)indexOfItem:(nonnull AAPLListItem *)item;
```

https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25